# debug dynamic js using chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In a web application all pages are loading using ajax. Some pages have there own js file which are loaded after the new page added. I want to debug that dynamic js added but in debugger of chrome I am not able to find that js file.

How to find that file for debugging?

Comment: Chrome console log has trace of the errors showing filenames. It should be a start. You can also "break" on errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the following in your code -

```
debugger;
```

Keep your scripts console open. As and when this line is encountered the debugger will wait at this point until you step further.

**Note**: Your scripts console should already be open since you cannot physically select which script file to debug. At run time, chrome will create a `program.js` dynamic file with the dynamically rendered js.

Comment: what if I dont have access to that js file on web server?